# Kernel Version Error, insmod fails

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kernel

I am running with kernel `version-2.6.35`

When I hit `uname -r` it gives as `2.6.35-22-generic`

Compiled a module from `Kernel-2.6.35` source tree,

But it **fails to insert the module** in my running kernel.

I don't have any clue.
can anybody help me out of this !!

Thank you.

Comment: It would help if u added more information like how u compiled the module? and what is the log printed out during the failure?

Comment: command I applied is: `make drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko`

and the error is: modules can not be inserted, with `error code -1`

Comment: check the dmesg logs if you may find anything like 'verification failed -1'

Comment: Where did you get the source tree from?

Answer (score 0):

Have to compile LKM against the correct kernel version i.e. output of **uname -r**. In your case you have downloaded the kernel version-2.6.35 source tree and compiled your LKM against it. While inserting LKM, checks for the **KERNEL_VERSION**, if they match will not get any errors while module insertion but if they mismatch fails to insert the module.

Answer (score 0):

You want to ensure that CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is enable in the running Kernel, `2.6.35-22-generic` in your case. When you the build a Kernel Module from the `2.6.35` sources the running Kernel will allow modules with matching symbols to be loaded or if symbols are missing, it'll fail to load.

Not having CONFIG_MODVERSIONS enabled means that you **MUST** match the version between the Kernel version and the module.

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that you are using the *official* kernel tree, but you are trying to load your module in your distribution. You must you the kernel source/header from your Linux distribution. I am supposing this because of this version `2.6.35-22-generic`, `-22-generic` it is not part of the official version name.